# How can I create "My Computer" toolbar at the top of the Desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, toolbar

In previous versions of Windows, I have been able to "drag and drop" the My Computer icon to the top or sides of the desktop and convert it into a toolbar.  The toolbar could be set "always on top" or "autohide".  I found this a very convenient way to have instant access to all my drives with NO clicks.

Windows 7 does not appear to have this functionality.  Is there any way to recreate a My Computer toolbar at the top of the Desktop in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4):

This was called a "DeskBand." DeskBands are the extra toolbars which were available (and which you could create from any folder or shell object). Those toolbars could be attached to the Start Bar, or docked to one side of the screen (and auto-hidden, as you mention), or just free-floating on the desktop.

Unfortunately, in Windows Vista, Microsoft deprecated the concept of "floating" DeskBands. This term was used to refer to any DeskBand which was not docked to the Start Bar. I believe Vista included the feature (though I can't confirm this), but it was already put on notice at that point for Win7.

[Win7 removed it entirely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_removed_in_Windows_7). You can create custom toolbars (I have), but they all have to live within the confines of the TaskBar. This makes me very sad personally, because it means I need to find or code a custom app launcher. (Start Menu doesn't cut it, and my 5 custom toolbars -- even shrunk down to nothing but labels -- are eating too much horizontal real estate on the TaskBar.)

Answer (score 3):

I use [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com) to get an OS X-like toolbar on my Vista laptop. The level of customizatoin that it offers borders on ridiculous. You can flatten out the 'dock to closely resemble your old toolbar although I think you will enjoy some of the improved functionality.

For example, I have mine display large icons, dock against the top of the screen, stay on top of open windows and auto-hide when not in use.