# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Create a 'Magic' Toolbar

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

In Vista you can create a 'Magic' toolbar thus:

Go to the desktop and create a plain folder, then, when you drag it to the edge of the desktop a miracle takes place, the folder transforms into a toolbar.

Is it possible to re-create this effect in Windows Server 2008 R2, or in Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. These are called [DeskBands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx), and "floating" deskbands (that is, ones not directly attached to and docked within the primary TaskBar) are deprecated as of Windows Vista. (I haven't tried these on Server 2008 R2; unknown if they work at all in that environment.)

As of Windows 7, DeskBands must occupy the same space as the taskbar itself. This is a shame, and a personal annoyance to me, because I used this trick to create shortcut bars with all my apps in the past. (I didn't need it in Vista, where I had a Sidebar gadget for launching; but with Sidebar no longer occupying the far-right and able to be always-on-top, that option is useless now to me as well.)

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/31342/how-can-i-create-my-computer-toolbar-at-the-top-of-the-desktop-in-windows-7/31350#31350) for more information.

Comment: Guy's Conclusion
Floating Deskbands depreciated in Vista.
'Magic Toolbars' depreciated in Windows 7.