# Windows 8 - Desktop quick access toolbar?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, toolbar

I want new bar on my desktop screen (like Quick Access Bar) but unlike the Quick Access Bar where you add the shortcuts, I want a bar which focuses solely on the Desktop folder. The bar monitors the desktop folder and displays shortcuts to all the files inside it.

My questions:

1. Does such a bar exist? (I tried research, but only found bars like Quick Access Bar)
2. How can I design my own?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the Taskbar and adding a new toolbar for the Desktop folder?

Comment: Similar: [How can I create “My Computer” toolbar at the top of the Desktop in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/31342/how-can-i-create-my-computer-toolbar-at-the-top-of-the-desktop-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the Taskbar, select **Tool Bar** and then select **Desktop**.

[image]

If that doesn't already exist, select **New Toolbar...**, and then navigate to and select your Desktop folder.

Once done, the toolbar and it's expander should be visible on the Taskbar.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change appearance of such toolbar to show an icon instead of the "Desktop" text as that example? I know it is possible to hide tile and text of that toolbar, but it will show the first item in the folder, generally a folder icon... I would like, for example, to put a logo, like the Windows flag on start menu...

Answer (score 1):

I am already aware of the Create New Toolbar approach, but one thing I hate is expandable menus. Navigating with mouse with precision requires immense concentration and careful gestures - something I'm not too fond of.

So, using AutoHotkey Scripting, I have created my own toolbar which is readily accessible and displays the files nicely:

My toobar has these features:

- On start, it asks to select a folder (if not already chosen from a previous launch)
- The Toolbar location is at the top of the screen
- It auto-hides - good feature as it doesn't take up your desktop workspace
- Bar shows on by moving mouse to top-left screen corner
- Bar has: Button to root folder, and
- Next to it links, in a horizontal list, all the files in that folder
- Right click on bar to Change folder
- Toolbar updates the file list links as they change when deleted/added inside the folder (so it's always updated).

Screenshot

[Desktop](http://s23.postimg.org/uebhjccaz/DT_Desktop.png)

[My Pictures](http://s7.postimg.org/dv89q742z/DT_My_Pics.png)

Thanks for the help anyway :)